# python web-scraping ==> Google search

Tags: python

I need help because I'm stuck. So I'm actually on Web-scraper project, and the problem is that I can't manage to get the right "a" tags of the searched words, i only get the one of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or the URL that i use is:

```
   url_dorked ="https://www.google.com/search?q={}&sources=lnms&tbs=nws".format(dork_used)
```

When I try the URL on my browser, he displays me the right page. But the python script receive only the tags of the Home page of google.

Here is the full script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Codded by Naylor From Exploit-Zone
#Join-us ! ==> https://forum.exploit-zone.eu/
#Create a folder nammed ==> Dork

from urllib.request import *
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

"""
http ==> 80
https ==> 443
----------
200 ==> OK
400 ==> Bad request
403 ==> Forbidden
404 ==> Not found
"""

def checker():
    dork_used = ""
    url_dorked ="https://www.google.co.ve/?gws_rd=cr&ei=DgBqVpWJMoPA-gHy25fACg#q={}".format(dork_used)
    dorks = open("Dork/{}.txt".format(txtdork_path),"r")
    list_dorks = []
    dorks_lines = dorks.readlines()
    tot_dorks = len(dorks_lines)
    tot_dorks -= 1
    for line in dorks_lines:
      list_dorks.append(line)
      print("\t{}\n (--) Has been charged\n".format(line))
    print("\n(--) All {} dorks charged\n".format(tot_dorks))
    dorks.close()
    choosen_dork = int(input("Witch line do you want to use ? (write a number between 0 and {})\n>".format(tot_dorks)))
    if choosen_dork >= 0 and choosen_dork <= tot_dorks:
        pass
    else:
        print("The choosen number is to big !")
        choosen_dork = int(input("Witch line do you want to use ? (write a number between 0 and {})\n>".format(tot_dorks)))
    dork_used = str(list_dorks[choosen_dork])
    print("\n(--) Selected Dorks ==> {}".format(dork_used))

    req_fbypss = Request(url_dorked, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) #user-agent to bypass Anti-crawl)
    init_google = urlopen(req_fbypss)#init connection
    print("(--) Google connection response ==> {}\n".format(init_google.code))
    html_google = init_google.read() #read response of init
    html_decoded = html_google.decode("utf-8")#like ISO-8859-1
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_google, "html.parser") #start an html html_parser
    result_link = soup.findAll('a')
    for i in result_link:
        print(i,"\n")
    """
    with open("dork_{}.txt".format(choosen_dork),"a") as f:
        for result in result_1:
            f.write(result)
    """

print("\n\n\welcome\n\n")
print("here Are the available dork file :\n")
dork_list = str(os.listdir('Dork/.'))
print("=> {}\n".format(dork_list))

txtdork_path = str(input("Enter dork file's name (without '.txt'/'[]'/''')\n>"))

check_file = os.path.isfile("Dork/{}.txt".format(txtdork_path))

if check_file == True:
    print("\n(--) {} as been selected".format(txtdork_path))
else:
    print("\nWrong name!\n (write only the name of the .txt file like : Google dork 2019)\n the .txt file have to be on the Dork folder\n\n")
    exit()
checker()
```

The script isn't finish it's only a dev version.

The result of my research are:

-either there is an anti-crawler and the User-Agent doesn't bypass him.

-either it's a problem from the URL, and I have to modify her.

Thanks for helping me ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
def checker():
    dork_used = ""
    url_dorked ="https://www.google.co.ve/?gws_rd=cr&ei=DgBqVpWJMoPA-gHy25fACg#q={}".format(dork_used)
```

When `url_dorked` is assigned, `dork_used` is an empty string, therefore `q=` is empty.  Did you intend that?

Also, I believe it should be `&q={}`, not `#q={}`.

Comment: i respond but i think you didn't see (i respond as a post)

Answer (score 0):

I follow your advice and replace the code to :

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Codded by Naylor From Exploit-Zone
#Join-us ! ==> https://forum.exploit-zone.eu/
#Create a folder nammed ==> Dork

from urllib.request import *
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

"""
http ==> 80
https ==> 443
----------
200 ==> OK
400 ==> Bad request
403 ==> Forbidden
404 ==> Not found
"""

def checker():
    dorks = open("Dork/{}.txt".format(txtdork_path),"r")
    list_dorks = []
    dorks_lines = dorks.readlines()
    tot_dorks = len(dorks_lines)
    tot_dorks -= 1
    for line in dorks_lines:
      list_dorks.append(line)
      print("\t{}\n (--) Has been charged\n".format(line))
    print("\n(--) All {} dorks charged\n".format(tot_dorks))
    dorks.close()
    choosen_dork = int(input("Witch line do you want to use ? (write a number between 0 and {})\n>".format(tot_dorks)))
    if choosen_dork >= 0 and choosen_dork <= tot_dorks:
        pass
    else:
        print("The choosen number is to big !")
        choosen_dork = int(input("Witch line do you want to use ? (write a number between 0 and {})\n>".format(tot_dorks)))
    dork_used = str(list_dorks[choosen_dork])
    print("\n(--) Selected Dorks ==> {}".format(dork_used))

    url_dorked ="https://www.google.com/search?q={}&sources=lnms&tbs=nws".format(dork_used)

    req_fbypss = Request(url_dorked, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) #user-agent to bypass Anti-crawl)
    init_google = urlopen(req_fbypss)#init connection
    print("(--) Google connection response ==> {}\n".format(init_google.code))
    html_google = init_google.read() #read response of init
    html_decoded = html_google.decode("ISO-8859-1")#like utf-8
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_google, "html.parser") #start an html html_parser
    result_link = soup.findAll('a')
    for i in result_link:
        print(i,"\n")
    """
    with open("dork_{}.txt".format(choosen_dork),"a") as f:
        for result in result_1:
            f.write(result)
    """

print("\n\n\tWelcome\n\n")
print("here Are the available dork file :\n")
dork_list = str(os.listdir('Dork/.'))
print("=> {}\n".format(dork_list))

txtdork_path = str(input("Enter dork file's name (without '.txt'/'[]'/''')\n>"))

check_file = os.path.isfile("Dork/{}.txt".format(txtdork_path))

if check_file == True:
    print("\n(--) {} as been selected".format(txtdork_path))
else:
    print("\nWrong name!\n (write only the name of the .txt file like : Google dork 2019)\n the .txt file have to be on the Dork folder\n\n")
    exit()
checker()
```

so I replace the url_dorked because the one that I put was a wrong one that I forgot to replace ^^

and i change the place of the url_dorked to put him after the selection of dork_used

one thing change he asks now to decode with ISO-8859-1 instead of utf-8
but still don't work :/